# How to count a keyword in a series of text strings within multiple cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've found similar ideas on here by using SEARCH or FIND in Excel, but those seem to be more about finding the location of the keyword, rather than counting how many times it comes up.

I have a CSV of a shot list. Each shot is associated with a sequence, and each shot has a set of "tags" (this is the text string).  Please see below for an example:

[image]

There are two main keywords I'd like to keep track of: "dog" and "fox". There are multiple shots per sequence, and my goal is to figure out how many shots per sequence have the "dog" tag and how many have the "fox" tag.  The formula I need would be for the columns highlighted yellow, and I have manually entered the first few entires to give an idea of what number should be there.  Once those are filled in, I can then count the ratio per sequence of which ones are tagged more for "dog" or "fox".

I can't use text-to-columns in Excel to easily break down the text string column, because each one contains a different series of tags (somewhat demonstrated by my sample text).

I've figured out a simple formula to count what I want if the text column only had "dog" or "fox" in it, but I can't figure out how to get Excel to find one word within a text string and count it.

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,B:B,1,F:F,"dog")
```

1 being the sequence number, and the rest of the columns are referencing my larger data sheet.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Edit:
Sheet in text form here (sorry about formatting, cant upload a file from work ATM):

```
COUNTER      SAMPLE DATA
Sequence    Total Fox   Total Dog   Total Entries   Ratio Fox   Ratio Dog       Sequence    Shot    Text
1   2   2   4   0.5 0.5     1   mov_101 The quick brown fox
2   3   2   5   0.6 0.4     2   mov_102 jumps over the lazy dog
3           4               3   mov_103 The fox and the hound
4           2               4   mov_104 fox news
5           3               5   mov_105 I am a dog
                            1   mov_106 The fox and the hound
                            2   mov_107 jumps over the lazy dog
                            3   mov_108 The fox and the hound
                            4   mov_109 jumps over the lazy dog
                            5   mov_110 I am a dog
                            1   mov_111 jumps over the lazy dog
                            3   mov_112 The fox and the hound
                            5   mov_113 The fox and the hound
                            2   mov_114 jumps over the lazy dog
                            2   mov_115 fox news
                            1   mov_116 I am a dog
                            3   mov_117 I am a dog
                            2   mov_118 The fox and the hound
```

Comment: Please put the data directly in the post, highlight and hit Ctrl-K so we do not need to retype your data to test answers.  If you can not format it properly leave it there and someone will format it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you need to use **`COUNTIFS`** instead of **`SUMIFS`** to get the count of sequences. And use **`"*"`** around word **`fox`** and **`dog`** to consider surrounding words.

Here is the formula that I've used to get fox count:

```
=COUNTIFS($H:$H,$A2,$J:$J,"*fox*")
```

Place this formula in cell **`B2`** and drag it down.
Same way, following formula will get you the dog count per sequence:

```
=COUNTIFS($H:$H,$A2,$J:$J,"*dog*")
```

Place this formula in cell **`C2`** and drag it down.

So I tried to replicate your data and this is what I've used:

[image]

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you! I think all I really needed was the asterisk surrounding my keyword in the formula.  However, I tried changing my `SUMIFS` with `COUNTIFS`, and got the error "You've entered too few arguments for this function".    So now my working formula reads as follows: `=SUMIFS('referenceSheet'!D:D,'referenceSheet'!B:B,"1",'referenceSheet'!G:G,"*dog*")`

Comment: My **`COUNTIFS`** formula worked with given test data without any issues. Chances you might be having different data? Anyway glad to help. :)

Comment: Yes I think that is the issue--I tried to simplify my data (can't post my exact data for security reasons) into the dog/fox scenario, but it's a bit more complicated than that. Luckily you still gave me the answer I was looking for! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Someone will probably have a better solution than this, but I've used it before when looking for a similar function and couldn't find one.

```
=(LEN([textcell]) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE([textcell], [wordcell], ""))) / LEN([wordcell])
```

What this does is compare the length of the original string, with the length of the string with the search word removed. Dividing it by the length of the word, giving you how many occurrences were removed.

So given the following content :

```
fox dog search
1   0   The quick brown fox
0   1   jumps over the lazy dog
```

The formula on A2 is

```
=(LEN($C2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE($C2,A$1, ""))) / LEN(A$1)
```

Dollar signs not required, but made it so I could copy the formula to all 4 cells.

Comment: This seems interesting but I'm not sure if it will work for me. To clarify, my text strings (the tags) are not all the same lengths. Maybe I just don't understand your formula because I don't see how it's searching for the keyword.

Comment: They don't have to have the same length. Let's say your sentence is 24 characters long. If your word has 5 characters in it, and appears once, then the new length of the line (with the word removed) would be 19. The difference is 5, which divided by the original word length would be 1 (or the number of occurrences). If it appeared twice, the new length would be 14. ((24 - 14) / 5) = 2 (the number of occurrences). Change the cell "A1" (fox" to "brown") -- you'll find it still gives an answer of 1. Now change "B1" ("dog" to "o"). Should come up with 2 on the second item.

Answer (score 0):

If your Sequence column is E, and the column with text is F, you could use this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(B$1,$F$2:$F$6)))),--($E$2:$E$6=$A2))`

This creates two arrays, one that's a sequence of 1's and 0's where 1 is that the text contains B1 ("fox" or "dog"), and another that is 1 for sequence matching and 0 for not sequence matching.

Then it multiplies and sums the arrays so you only get the count of when both conditions match.

The formula is in cells B2:C3 in my example:

Picture of sample data I used:[image: sample data]